# Sanic and Motor use different event loops

Tags: python, motordriver, sanic

I am new to Sanic and I am trying to get it to work with Motor. I did manage to get everything to work in a single file, however, when I try it out within my project structure, I am running into the below issues.

```
[2018-02-28 17:26:58 +0530] [3720] [ERROR] Traceback (most recent call 
last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sanic/app.py", line 556, in 
handle_request
response = await response
File "/usr/src/Python-3.6.4/Lib/asyncio/coroutines.py", line 129, in throw
return self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
File "/home/msambare/Documents/Projects/Snippets/Sanic-Motor-
Issue/IAC/src/MyPackgae/REST/user_REST.py", line 42, in post
request.json['last']
File "/usr/src/Python-3.6.4/Lib/asyncio/coroutines.py", line 129, in throw
return self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
File "/home/msambare/Documents/Projects/Snippets/Sanic-Motor-
Issue/IAC/src/MyPackgae/DAO/user_DAO.py", line 40, in register_user
result = await db.users.insert_one(serialized_user)
RuntimeError: Task <Task pending coro=<Sanic.handle_request() running at 
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sanic/app.py:556> created at 
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sanic/server.py:299> got Future 
<Future pending cb=[run_on_executor.<locals>._call_check_cancel() at 
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/motor/frameworks/asyncio/__init__.py:85]> attached to a different 
loop
```

I did some research and as mentioned on the GitHub pages of Sanic, tried the 'before-server-block' section for db setup. That works in a single file, however, not in my project structure.

My project structure looks something like:

[Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lq7q0.jpg)

Below is my code. I have recreated the issue in a simpler structure without losing the essence.

*src/MyPackage/Model/user.py*

```
class User(object):
def __init__(self, first, last):
    self.first = first
    self.last = last
```

*src/MyPackage/UC/user_uc.py*

```
from Model import User
from DAO import User_DAO


class User_UC(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._user = None

    def create_user(self, first, last):
        self._user = User(first, last)
        ud = User_DAO()
        id = ud.register_user(
            {
                'first': first,
                'last': last
            }
        )
        return id
```

*src/DAO/motor_connection.py*

```
import uvloop
import asyncio
import motor.motor_asyncio


asyncio.set_event_loop_policy(uvloop.EventLoopPolicy())


class Motor_Connection(object):
    """ Provides a MongoDB connection and sets the DB to be used.

    The class implements the Singleton pattern.
    """

    __instance = None

    def __new__(cls):
        if Motor_Connection.__instance is None:
            Motor_Connection.__instance = object.__new__(cls)

            Motor_Connection.__instance.client = \
                motor.motor_asyncio.AsyncIOMotorClient(
                    'localhost',
                    27017,
                    io_loop=asyncio.get_event_loop()
                )

            Motor_Connection.__instance.db = \
                Motor_Connection.__instance.client.test_database

        return Motor_Connection.__instance.db
```

*src/DAO/user_DAO.py*

```
from DAO import Motor_Connection


db = Motor_Connection()


class User_DAO(object):
    async def register_user(self, serialized_user):
        result = await db.users.insert_one(serialized_user)
        return result.inserted_id
```

*src/MyPackage/REST/user_REST.py*

```
from sanic.views import HTTPMethodView
from sanic.response import text
from UC import User_UC


class User_REST(HTTPMethodView):
    async def post(self, request):
        user_uc = User_UC()
        id = await user_uc.create_user(
            request.json['first'],
            request.json['last']
        )
        return text(id)
```

and finally the main program...

*src/MyPackage/main.py*

```
from sanic import Sanic
from DAO import Motor_Connection
from REST import User_REST


app = Sanic()


@app.listener('before_server_start')
def init(sanic, loop):
    global db
    db = Motor_Connection()


app.add_route(User_REST.as_view(), '/')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=8000, workers=3, debug=True)
```

I have not included the **init**.py files of any of the sub-packages. The only thing that I have done in those files is bringing the classes to the sub-package level.

From what I have been able to figure out, it seems in main.py when the User_Rest class is imported which in turn imports the User_UC class which imports the User_DAO class which in turn imports the Motor_Connection class - this is where the mess happens. This creates a separate event loop which is not shared by Sanic.

So, if my understanding is correct, all the chained imported classes use one event loop and Sanic uses another event loop. I know we cannot have 2 event loops but I am unable to figure out what needs to be done to sort this out.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok. The issue is resolved. I had to use global variables to resolve it. Please find the modified code below for reference.

*main.py*

```
from sanic import Sanic
from DAO import Motor_Connection
from REST import User_REST
import commons


app = Sanic()


@app.listener('before_server_start')
def init(sanic, loop):
    commons.db = Motor_Connection()


app.add_route(User_REST.as_view(), '/')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=8000, workers=3, debug=True)
```

*commons.globals.py*

```
db = None
```

*user_DAO.py*

```
import commons


class User_DAO(object):
    async def register_user(self, serialized_user):
        result = await commons.db.users.insert_one(serialized_user)
        return result.inserted_id
```

**Explanation:** While the motor connection class was a singleton and returned the same instance, as it was initialized during the imports, Sanic could not get a handle on the event loop. Sanic has to be initialized first to be able to get a handle on the event loop.

By using a global variable and initializing it in the before_server_start block, Sanic gets the handle. Now when you use the same variable in the DAO class, you have access to Sanic's event loop.